# Python 3.3 interpreter and one-liner issue (4 lines statement works fine...)

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x, append

It's my first message here, I'm student and I'm starting to learn python with a teacher that is really keen on python one-liners.. 
And I've got some troubles with python interpreter, here my problem:

I've got some troubles with python interpreter, I want to convert a 4 line `if`/`else` statement to a one-liner in a functional program.

The code :

```
  # ll is a {}

  # with one index initialized like this:
  # {'': ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word n', '...']}
  # with a lot of word from a book

  i, a=0, ll['']
  # so here a is an array like: ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word n', '...']

  while i < len(a)-1:
      i+=1
      if a[i-1] not in ll:
          ll[a[i-1]]=[a[i]]
      else:
          ll[a[i-1]].append(a[i])
```

This works well, but if I try to replace this:

```
if a[i-1] not in ll:
    ll[a[i-1]]=[a[i]]
else:
    ll[a[i-1]].append(a[i])
```

This this one-liner:

```
ll[a[i-1]] = [a[i]] if a[i-1] not in ll else ll[a[i-1]].append(a[i])
```

Then, I get this error output:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

(It works on the first iterations, arrays are filled properly, then the array is suddenly changed to a `None`... Never seen this with the 4 lines statement that is the same.. Please help me)

Details: I'm on Windows with Python 3.3.4 (installed from python.org)

Of course, the one liner program should work properly with not much data like in my example but in my real program it fails with the above error... It's really annoying! Is this a python bug? (For me clearly yes and it's not the only one I've encountered even if I'm a beginner.)

Comment: `append` modifies the list in-place, and will `return None`. This is not a bug!

Comment: I know it, but why it can't take an existing list and put a string like "should" in it ?? that's a bug..

Comment: It should work normally and it work in my if / else statement as I've explained, please read my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `else` case, you are setting

```
ll[a[i-1]] = ll[a[i-1]].append(a[i])
```

Where `append` will modify the list in-place correctly but `return None`, which you then assign back to the dictionary, replacing the list and causing the error the next time you access that key.

---

The minimal change is to add to the list each time:

```
ll[a[i-1]] = [a[i]] if a[i-1] not in ll else ll[a[i-1]] + [a[i]]
```

However, this is not very efficient, as it creates a new list (rather than modifying the old one) each time.

---

Generally, if you are dealing with pairs of words, I would recommend using `zip` and [`islice` from `itertools`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to pair them up. Using a [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for the output will save you manually checking the lists already exist.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import islice

out = defaultdict(list)
for word1, word2 in zip(words, islice(words, 1, None)):
    out[word1].append(word2)
```

This isn't a one-liner, but will be more efficient.

Comment: So, how could I do to either affect a value or append a new one if the array already exists? :(
Thanks

Comment: Updated with options for fixing the problem

Comment: Nice effort, thank you very much, thanks to your first post I have figured out in the mean time by using 

ll[a[i-1]]=ll[a[i-1]]+[a[i]] if a[i-1] in ll else [a[i]] 


OK it's not efficient as you've said but it will do it for the exercise !!

THANKS AGAIN !!

Regards,

Comment: Thx, I was tearing my hairs out on this problem x')